# Propogating NA when computing an operation on two vectors/variables with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two vectors, A and B. I am computing a new vector, C, from A and B using mutate in dyplyr. The operation is a sum as I just want to concatenate the two variables into one (scores from a separate analyses within binary sex). In the case where both vectors have NA for a given row, I need the new vector C to reflect NA, not 0. Currently I am using:

```
DF=mutate(DF, C = rowSums(cbind(A, B), na.rm = T))
```

But this gives a '0' value if both A and B vectors have NA. I have scoured other posts on similar themes but can not distill what I need from them.

Comment: Why not just `mutate(DF, C = A+B)`? Any `NA` values will propagate that way as well. Or do you want it to return the value of A when B is `NA`, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a dplyr one-liner. It works because `dplyr::coalesce` outputs the first non-NA it receives. So if the sum can be computed it uses that, otherwise it outputs the non-NA value, or if both are NA, you get NA.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(c = coalesce(a+b, a, b))


## A tibble: 4 x 3
#      a     b     c
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    NA     1
#2    NA    NA    NA
#3    NA     2     2
#4     2     3     5
```

(Using cardinal40's sample `df`)

```
df <- tibble(a = c(1, NA, NA, 2),
             b = c(NA, NA, 2, 3))
```

Comment: Awesome solution

Comment: This is fantastic!, but how do I ensure the new vector C is appended to my existing df? I get the output in the editor, but I want the new column added to DF so I can see it when I 'fix' the DF object.

Comment: `df <- df %>% mutate(c = coalesce(a+b, a, b))` will replace the original `df` with a version including the new column.

Comment: Perfect. To be sure of myself, the coalesce command is instructing dplyr to concatenate the two vectors using whatever operation is user-specified?

Comment: It identifies the first non-missing value: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/coalesce.html

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `na.rm` removes the NA and if there are no NA, it returns 0.  To change those case, we can have another logic into it

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
   mutate(C = rowSums(.[c("A", "B")], na.rm = TRUE) *
            NA^!rowSums(!is.na(.[c("A", "B")])))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#      A     B     C
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    NA     1
#2    NA    NA    NA
#3    NA     2     2
#4     2     3     5
```

#### data

```
DF <- structure(list(A = c(1, NA, NA, 2), B = c(NA, NA, 2, 3)), row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option using `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <-
  tibble(
    a = c(1, NA, NA, 2),
    b = c(NA, NA, 2, 3)
  )

df %>% 
  mutate(
    c = case_when(
      is.na(a) & is.na(b) ~ NA_real_,
      is.na(a) ~ b,
      is.na(b) ~ a,
      TRUE ~ a + b
    )
  )

# A tibble: 4 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    NA     1
2    NA    NA    NA
3    NA     2     2
4     2     3     5
```